# Read files from the internet?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7

When I retrieve a URL (By sending a request to random.cat) as so:

```
print('Importing REQUESTS')
import requests
import json
import urllib
response = (requests.get("http://random.cat/meow"))
response = str(response.content)
print(response)
response = response.replace("b'","")
response = response.replace("'","")
response = response.replace("\\","")
print(response)
data = json.loads(response)
print (data["file"])`
```

Then I attempt to open it using:

```
with open(line, 'rb') as f:
    print("work")`
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/catimages.py", line 21, in <module>
    with open(line, 'rb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'http://random.cat/i/8Vilp.jpg' `
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`open` can't directly open URL's. You'll need to use requests to download the file first. See [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Edit: To be clear, the error message you provided indicates that the value of `line` is `'http://random.cat/i/8Vilp.jpg'`, so you are attempting to call `open('http://random.cat/i/8Vilp.jpg', 'rb')` which will not work.